# network proxy and python

Tags: python, networking, proxy

If I set network proxy in network settings on my computer (gnome 3 , fedora) when I do post get reuests in my python script will they go through the proxy or through direct connection?

what will python use? chrome browser gets proxified when I set proxy in neetwork, same for python?

if so how to use direct connection from python? like firefox does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you connect to remote servers via Python. The `urllib` and `urllib2` libraries will honour the `*_PROXY` environment variables (e.g. `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, etc.). From the [`urllib` documentation page](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html):

> The urlopen() function works transparently with proxies which do not require authentication. In a Unix or Windows environment, set the http_proxy, or ftp_proxy environment variables to a URL that identifies the proxy server before starting the Python interpreter.

Note that you can also use the `NO_PROXY` environment variable to list exceptions.

You'll need to be more specific about your Python network usage to be any more specific.

Comment: thnx thats what I'm looking for, so by default if no http_proxy option is set python will go through direct connection right?

Comment: Exactly. You can also use the `no_proxy` environment variable to list exceptions.